# Получаю data is invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, requests, новая-почта

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, почему получаю `Data is invalid`? Вот мой код:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

param = {
    "modelName": "Address",
    "calledMethod": "getCities",
    "methodProperties": {
        "Ref": "ebc0eda9-93ec-11e3-b441-0050568002cf"
        },
    "apiKey": api
}


r = requests.post('http://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json', data=param, headers=headers)

print(r.content)
```

Ответ программы:

```
 {"success":false,"data":[],"errors":["Data is invalid"],"translatedErrors":[],"warnings":[],"info":[],"messageCodes":[],"errorCodes":[],"warningCodes":[],"infoCodes":[]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Посмотрел в API](https://devcenter.novaposhta.ua/docs/services/556d7ccaa0fe4f08e8f7ce43/operations/556d885da0fe4f08e8f7ce46/console) и там в URL указывается еще `/Address/getCities` (еще лучше использовать параметр `json=` для отправки `json`):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0',
}

param = {
    "modelName": "Address",
    "calledMethod": "getCities",
    "methodProperties": {
        "Ref": "ebc0eda9-93ec-11e3-b441-0050568002cf"
    },
    "apiKey": api
}

r = requests.post('http://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/Address/getCities', json=param, headers=headers)
print(r.content)
```